# Json filter data on the sibling node

Tags: json, jsonpath

I am new with JSONPath and any help is appreciated. I am trying to filter data based on its sibling value.

My JSON sample:

```
[

  {
  "id": "10300",
  "name": "NAME1"
  },
  {
  "id": "10500",
  "name": "NAME2"
  }
 ]
```

And I would like to query id by the name. I tried something like this, but without luck:

```
$..id[?(@name=='NAME1')]
```

I am sure I missed something trivial.

Answer (score 18):

I found the solution by myself after all.

```
$..[?(@.name == 'NAME1')].id
```